# Comparing numbers inside of an array

Tags: c, arrays, compare

Values are entered into an array by the user and then i have this For Loop to compare the numbers once they have all been entered. What i'm trying to do is find the first larger number in the array.

```
i = 0;
next = a[++i];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > a[next])
    {
        ++next;

        if (a[i] < a[next])
        {
          printf("%d is the first larger number.", a[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

When I debug my program I see that when "i" is being compared to a[next] its not taking the value of the number inside that position "i" of the array. i've attempted using "i" instead of a[i] when starting my If statements but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Here is my Corrected code. made a few more minor changes just for practice

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
const int len = 4;
int a[len];
int i;
int j = a[i-1];

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}

i = 0;
for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[j])
    {
          printf("%d is the first larger number.", a[i]);
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: what u are doing is not obvious, can u give two examples? 1: what u want the output to be, 2: what does it output now?

Comment: `++next` will increment `next` - it will **not** set next to be the next element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the first place where the array is not decreasing; i.e., the index of the first element `i` such that `a[i] > a[i-1]`.

```
for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i-1]) {
        printf("%d is the first larger number", a[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

A new version, printing out the first part of the sequence:

```
for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i-1]) {
        printf("\n%d is the first larger number", a[i]);
        break;
    }
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: okay that makes a little more sense. Now i want also want to print out  say for instance a[i-1] < a[i] until i got to a larger number would i write this into the same for Loop using an else if statement or should i just create another loop entirely? @bytbox

Comment: A second loop is probably simplest, since otherwise you'll have to manually keep track of which of the two you've already printed.

Comment: why second loop? just put `else printf("%d\n", a[i]);` inside your loop

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood. @Zanderg, if chouaib's comment does it for you, ignore what I said.

Comment: Thank you @bytbox ya i was able to figure it out. i added my corrections below my question code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for the first local maximum, one solution is to declare a variable called `best` to keep track of the largest number seen so far. Set `best` to the first element of the array `a[0]`. Then check for the first element of the array that is less than `best`.

```
best = a[0]; 
for ( i = 1; i < len; i++ )
{
    if ( a[i] > best ) 
        best = a[i];
    else if ( a[i] < best )
        break;
}
printf( "%d is the first larger number.\n", best );
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever what you are trying to achieve!! you never say:
`next = a[++i];`
than
`a[i] > a[next]` !! `a[next]` can be beyond the size of your array

EX:

`A[] = {0, 7, 2, 3, 1}`

`next = A[1] = 7`

`A[next] = A[7] = !! //what u think it is?`